# How to set at-least-once strategy for actor?

Tags: scala, akka

I have several actors that communicate with each other and most of the time the messages, that were sent, does not reach the other actor.

For example, when the actor `A` sends messages to `B` and most of the case, the actor `B` does not receive the messages from `A` at all. 
Running the test, sometimes failed sometimes passed, so the behavior is so unpredictable.

How to guarantee the at-least-one delivery? Where do I have to enable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka, by default, supports [at-most-once](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#the-general-rules) message delivery. To enable at-least-once guarantees, use [Akka Persistence](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence.html#at-least-once-delivery).

Akka Typed does not support at-least-once delivery [yet](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20984).

Comment: I use akka typed. Does it support at-least-once guarantees?